What is the meaning of a tilde in a type conformance declaration?
I recently saw that the Optional enum is declared as follows:
enum Optional<Wrapped> where Wrapped : ~Copyable

And the ExpressibleByNilLiteral protocol is declared as follows:
protocol ExpressibleByNilLiteral : ~Copyable

What does the ~ before Copyable mean in the type conformance? I found no reference to this in the Swift book, not even in the Summary of Grammar section.
I know the ~ before a number is the bitwise not operator. And ~= is the pattern matching operator.

You might find SE-0437 Noncopyable Standard Library Primitives interesting, it explains the changes made to these exact types.

The ~ indicates the suppression of a requirement.
By default, every generic type parameter has an implicit constraint that requires it to be Copyable.
E.g. when you write:
struct Foo<T> {}

It behaves as if you had:
struct Foo<T> where T: Copyable {}

The ~ suppresses this default requirement.
In your specific example, it means that Optional can be used with any kind of value of Wrapped, whether it's Copyable or not.
From SE-0427 Noncopyable Generics:

All possible types, both Copyable and noncopyable, can be substituted for T. This is the reason why we refer to ~Copyable as suppressing the conformance rather than inverting or negating it.


Now that I know this seems to be (currently) specific to the Copyable protocol, it turns out that the use of ~Copyable is mentioned in the documentation for Copyable. I looked everywhere but there before posting my question. :)

~ means "not". Swift 6 now has non-copyable types, so you can declare
struct S: ~Copyable { }

to mean "S is not copyable".
The use of ~Copyable in places where you would normally see generic constraints is rather confusing, because it's not a "constraint", but rather a "relaxation". Think of it as "need not".
enum Optional<Wrapped> where Wrapped : ~Copyable

means that the Wrapped type does not need to be copyable. It can be both copyable and and non-copyable types. It does not mean Wrapped must be non-copyable.
By default (if Wrapped: ~Copyable were removed), Wrapped would have to be a copyable type.
Similarly,
protocol ExpressibleByNilLiteral : ~Copyable

means that to conform to ExpressibleByNilLiteral, the conformer does not need to be copyable.
At the time of writing, ~ can only be applied to Copyable. There is also the experimental "non-escapable types" feature that allows ~Escapable.

I fear the opening line is going to confuse readers. It's "not" as in "not constrained to Codable", rather than "constrained to not codable". That distinction is pretty nuanced, so many of the SE proposals, forums posts, etc. have discouraged framing it as negation (which is e.g. why it doesn't use the ! symbol). If it had to be summarized as one word, "possibly" might be a better choice, as in where Wrapped: possibly Codable

@Alexander I like to think of those situations as "need not", as in Wrapped "need not" be copyable, and I think I explained that adequately in the answer. I edited to try to clarify.

Ah yes, that's a good framing. Yeah the rest of the answer is accurate and on-point, but I fear that a cursory skim-over from a google searcher who lands here might leave them with the wrong takeaway
